# Given $\{ x_n\}$ be a sequence of rational numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^{x_n}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

> Let a be a positive real number $a>0$ and $\{ x_n\}$ be a sequence of rational numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=0$ Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^{x_n}=1$

**My attempt**

given  = $e^{x_n \ln a} \to 1$

But any other alternative way? this was asked for 10 marks.

Comment: Have you learned anything about continuous functions? If not, then this attempt is not justified.

Comment: @xbh i studied about them .... i am a beginner. But the linkage between them and this given sequence  did not click to my brain. Kindly elaborate

Comment: In that case this is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prove this at a much more elementary level - long before you learn about logarithms, the exponential function, and continuous functions.

If $a=1$ then the proposition is trivial. Suppose you can prove it for all $a>1$; then it is also proved for all $a < 1$ (still $a > 0$), because $a^{x_n} = \big(\frac 1 a\big)^{-x_n}$, $\frac 1 a > 1$ if $a < 1$, and ${-x_n} \to 0$ if $x_n \to 0$.

Now let's fix $a > 1$. First let's show that $a^{\frac 1 n} \to 1$. Write $w_n = a^{\frac 1 n} - 1$; $w_n > 0$ and $a = (1 + w_n)^n \ge 1 + n \dot w_n$ (elementary inequality which can be proven by induction), so $w_n \le \frac{a-1} n$, which proves that $w_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, as claimed.

Then take an arbitrary sequence $x_n$ that converges to 0. For every $N \gg 0$, $x_n$ is between $-\frac 1 N$ and $\frac 1 N$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Conclude by using the special case we just finished proving.

Comment: sir but we did not use rational numbers fact. Will this hold for any $x_n$ a sequence of **real numbers** instead of just rational numbers? Pls correct me if i am wrong

Comment: In fact it will, as long as you know what that means in the first place. Raising a number to a power that is a rational number has an arithmetic definition. Real powers that are not rational are defined later in calculus - actually, perhaps later than where you encounter the question you asked! In any case, there are no such subtleties if the exponents are rational numbers. (The proof would work without any changes for real exponents though, once those are defined and their properties are proved.)

Comment: Tq sir......................

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that, in order to prove your statement, we are **not** allowed to directly cite the continuity over $\mathbb{R}$ of the exponential function . That's becsuse, the continuity over $\mathbb{R}$ of the exponential function is just built on the continuity over $\mathbb{Q}$ . Thus, if we cite the the continuity over $\mathbb{R}$ of the exponential function to prove the present statement, this work is nothing but **a circular argument**. Here, I give a proper proof for that.

Let $a>1$. If $a=1$,that is trivial; if $0<a<1$, the proof may be similar. Just as you assumed, $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n,\cdots $ is a rational number sequence with the limit $0$. Thus, $$|x_n|<\frac{1}{n}$$ holds starting from some term.  Hence $$-\frac{1}{n}<x_n <\frac{1}{n}.$$

We may readily obtain $$\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{1/n}<a^{x_n}<a^{1/n}.$$
But it's well-known that $x^{1/n} \to 1 (n \to \infty)$ for $x>0.$ Thus, by squeeze theorem,we have $$a^{x_n} \to 1.~~~(n \to \infty).$$

Comment: I don't understand - besides copying what I wrote, you added an obvious mistake in the proof. If $x_n \to 0$, how did you conclude that $|x_n|<\frac 1 n$ for $n$ sufficiently large? (That is obviously false; $x_n = \frac 2 n$ is a simple counter-example.) Moreover, "it's well-known that ..." and the thing that is well-known is a special case of the problem we are trying to solve; so that is NOT circular reasoning? Definite -1 for all these reasons.